# React-router auto redirect any route to root "/" except for "/main"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I used `react-router`, even tried `<Redirect .. />`, I can't redirect to the `/`, the main problem is the `/` is out of the other routes, so I need  to use `<Redirect from="*" to="" />`, it seems to not work.

then I also need to prevent `/main` redirecting to `/`, I put the `<Redirect .. >` after `<Route component={MainView} path="main">`

another requirement, how make the `localhost:3000` to `localhost:3000/` to use AppIndex `IndexRoute`

please check code below:

```
import MainView from 'components/MainView';
import ThemeIndex from 'components/ThemeIndex';
import AppIndex from 'components/ThemeIndex';
import Shop from 'components/Shop';
import App from 'components/App';

export default (
    <Route component={App} path="/">
      <IndexRoute component={AppIndex}></IndexRoute>
      <Route component={MainView} path="main">
        <IndexRoute component={ThemeIndex}></IndexRoute>
      </Route>
      <Redirect from="*" to="" />
    </Route>
);
```

have any idea?

Comment: Why do you want the trailing slash?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of leaving `to` an empty string, you have to specify the path, which means `<Redirect from="*" to="/" />` in this case.

To make the localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/, you don't have to do anything, your current code already get the job done.
If you go to any website's root URL, Say http://stackoverflow.com, and try type `location.pathname` in console, you'll get `"/"`

Please ask me if you have any other problem.

Answer (score 0):

agree with what David said , this section in the  [React router Redirect docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) briefs more clearly if there is any other use case :)

Comment: Link is outdated.